# Посчитать зарплату всех подчиненных с помощью 1-ой CTE

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsql-developer

```
create table test_table (
id integer not null,
name char(1) not null,
parent_id integer,
sum integer not null);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1, 'A', null, 300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11, 'B', 1, 2340);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(111, 'C', 11, 3200);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(22, 'D', 1, 7540);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2, 'E', null, 6300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3, 'F', 2, 8600);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(101, 'G', 3, 3800);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(102, 'H', 3, 9700);
```

Таблица.

Подобный вопрос уже задавали поэтому я просто приведу данный вопрос с уточнением.

как посчитать зарплату всех подчиненных, при этом зарплата начальника не учитывается.

```
select id, name, sum(sum)-max(root_sum)
  from (
    select connect_by_root(id) id, connect_by_root(name) name,
           connect_by_root(sum) root_sum, sum
      from test_table A
   connect by prior id=parent_id
  )
 group by id, name
```

Выше следует ответ прекрасного человека под ником Mike. 
Мой же вопрос заключается в следующем - как решить ту же самую задачу без использования connect by, а только лишь используя 1 CTE таблицу. Заранее спасибо. 
P.S.
Простите меня за такую наглость, что я в тупую копирую чужой вопрос. Но максимальное пока что, что я из себя выжал это решение задачи с 2-мя CTE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with RCTE(root_id,name,root_sum,sum,id) as(
    select id, name, sum, sum, id
      from test_table
  union all
    select R.root_id, R.name, R.root_sum, T.sum, T.id
      from RCTE R, test_table T
     where T.parent_id=R.id
)
select root_id, name, sum(sum)-max(root_sum)
  from RCTE
 group by root_id, name
```

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce4e98/3), вместе с запросом с `connect by`, по которому видно, что результаты обоих запросов одинаковы

Comment: Спасибо, но опять та же проблема. Не получается выстроить красивую иерархию.